# Integrable Function on interval

Tags: analysis, definite-integrals

Suppose f : [0,1] → R and g: [0,1] → R are such that for all x ∈ (0,1] we have f(x) = g(x).
Suppose f is Riemann integrable. Prove g is Riemann integrable and $\int_{0}^{1} f = \int_{0}^{1} g$

I'm not really sure how to start. I realize that the interval on which they are equal is (0,1] so they could be different at zero. But how does that matter regarding a solution?

Comment: What ways to do you know to show Riemann integrability?

Comment: if you can show $U(P, f) - L(P, f) < \epsilon $, where U and L denote the upper and lower darboux sums. Or if the upper darboux integral equals the lower darboux integral.

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $f$ is bounded, so is $g$.

If $P=(0,x_1,...,1)$ is any partition, then
$|L(f,P)-L(g,P)| = x_1 |\inf_{t \in [0,x_1]}f(t) - \inf_{t \in [0,x_1]}g(t)|= x_1|f(0)-g(0)|$, and a similar formula for $U$.

If $P'$ is a partition that refines $P$ then $L(f,P) \le L(f,P')$ and similarly
for $U$.

Let $\epsilon>0$ and choose $P$ such that $U(f,P)-L(f,P) < \epsilon$. Create a refinement
$P'$ by adding a new first point $x_1$ such that $x_1|f(0)-g(0)| < \epsilon$ (and hence
$|L(f,P')-L(g,P')| < \epsilon$). Then
$U(g,P') -L(g,P') < 3 \epsilon$. Hence $g$ is integrable.

Furthermore,
\begin{eqnarray}
|\int f - \int g | &\le& | \int f - L(f,P')| + | \int g -L(g,P')| + |L(f,P')-L(g,P') | \\
& \le & | U(f,P') - L(f,P')| + | U(g,P') -L(g,P')| + |L(f,P')-L(g,P') | \\
&\le& 5 \epsilon
\end{eqnarray}

Hence $\int f = \int g$.

**Notes**:

$U(g,P') -L(g,P') = U(g,P')-U(f,P')+U(f,P')-L(f,P')+L(f,P')-L(g,P')$.

Comment: That is a bit vague, you need to be more precise.

Comment: ok can you explain where the $3\epsilon$ is coming from

Comment: also I can't understand the first inequality in the last few strings of equations, can you explain a little bit more what each term means?

Comment: I can elaborate a little, but you need to do some work!

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you are asking about the terms in the first inequality? $\int f$ is the value of the integral. $U,L$ are the upper & lower Darboux sums.

Comment: Why the downvote, something wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Prove that $\int_0^1f-g=0$.

Comment: I'm not too good so this might be wrong- but can I say the following: Since f(x) = g(x) on $(0, 1]$ then f-g = 0 on that same interval, and since x=0 is a point it will not have area under the curve, therefore your hint is true and $\int_{0}^{1} f = \int_{0}^{1} g$?

Comment: The idea is correct, but that is not a formal proof.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $U(P, g)-L(P, g)\leq U(P, f) - L(P, f) + ???$

Try to fill in the question marks and proceed from there.

Comment: do you mind giving me another hint?

Comment: What causes the upper sum for g to differ from the sum for f?  And how much can that difference be at most?